# Remove vertical and horizontal lines

Tags: selections, image-editing

I have a picture of tall-ship-stations with a grid on it. I want to remove the grid so I can mirror the sides, convert to svg and have it laser cut.

[image: Ship stations]

I have done a bit of research beforehand, but none of the solutions I found was applicable to my specific case.

1. Line trace with low density - since all the lines are equally potent, this did not work.
2. Go by color - since both the stations and grid are same color, this did not work.
3. Ask on fiverr - no one would take the task and do it for me.
4. Google a program that could remove all vertical and horizontal lines - didn't find any.
5. Eraser tool on gimp - worked to some extent but it either corrupted the thickness of the lines or made small "crosses" appear where the lines intersected.
6. Ask a friend - All my designer friends are too busy.

Any hints or tips would be appreciated, preferred with free tools like gimp, inkscape, blender etc.

Comment: As long as you are going to convert this to an SVG, should you not be able to select individual lines and delete them in that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My friend, since this is just an image you have only two options:

Recreate the design without the lines.

Use photoshop and zoom-in until you see the pixels, grab the eraser and set the mode to Pencil and size to 1px and start erasing with precision like so:

[image]

---

### Update

I have added another image i made in under 2 minutes erasing some lines...Giving it more time makes it better, also, the crosses you mention are not due to the imprecision of the erase but by the opacity of the pixels.

This can be avoided by setting the eraser's opacity to say 10% and clicking on those pixels until you get a smooth transition between them (example in second image).

(1)

[image]

(2)

[image]

Comment: I don't have the original design. And i tried what you suggested (see pt, 5)

Comment: I did read that, I never used Gimp since I've been working with PS for almost 10 years and this can be done easily with some precision and patience in PS. I would estimate it taking about 35 minutes to do :) and with no sign of residue like the ones you mentioned :)

Comment: @Magic-Mouse I have made an update to the question so you can understand better what I'm saying :)

Comment: It appears that your analysis is correct, but how do i go from "before" to "after" ?

Comment: @Magic-Mouse Simply by changing the eraser opacity from 100% to say 10% and on each click it will erase 10% of the pixel's opacity, keep clicking till you get the smooth transition between the pixels ;)

Comment: Is it possible to go the other way ? Change the black line to 100 % black

Comment: @Magic-Mouse Well, you can by hitting Ctrl+L and typing 253 in the first input level (the dark one that has 0) but the result won't be as smooth.. try it